# Increase Number of Close Votes

Tags: discussion

If possible, it would be nice to see the the increase of close votes from 20 to something like 35-40. It seems like there are an abundance of Close Votes Reviews and once I hit 20 ( which is the queue limit ) I can only flag like 3 or 4 more posts under any of the other sections or any incoming questions that are off-topic.

Sure I have 100 flags but if I click "Off-Topic" it automatically tries to use one of my close vote flags which after review the daily Close Votes section under review, are pretty much used up.

Comment: I would support that but I don't know that we can do anything about it without the help of the higher powers.

Comment: This is definitely doable, but we need to include or escalate this to the system admins. [so] have 50 close votes for the day, with a maximum of 40 that can be used in review queue. Not sure if this was approved as a special priviledge due to the insane number of close votes in review queue. Currently from what I can see is that they have nearly 7K close votes in review queue

Comment: @PieterGoosen I like the the votes per day Stack has but find it weird it caps at 40 to leave only 10 close votes for the rest of the day ( outside of review ). I would like to see it more balanced maybe, 35 review limit, 15 in votes. Just getting on today there's 46 + ( 2 people * 19 already reviewed ) = 84 just today to close, with 5 people to close a question we either need more contributors or more close votes. I can't even imagine SO getting through all their closed votes but for smaller communities it would be helpful to keep up with the review queue.

Comment: The problem lies in contributors, not necessarily close vote limits. With the current problem we are having with our off topic policy, it makes contributors to our close vote review queue very causious and some even totally withdrew from doing any close voting, front end and review queue in back end. To be honest, I only cast close votes front end if a question is really really poor quality, otherwise I do not vote, even if posts are considered off topic in our current policy. My honest opinion, our current off topic policy is up to crap.

Comment: I really don't know if we ever are going to sort it out. There are even day and night differences between the mods on our current off topic policy. We really have more than enough 3K+ users to handle our review queue, we don't really need more close votes. We need a system that will encourage 3K+ users to participate in our review queues and keep those users in the review queues

Comment: @PieterGoosen I disagree with our off-topic policy being complete crap but at the same time it *does* need to change in some way. I don't know of a system that encourages 3K+ users to contribute more besides what's already in place. I think we need to bring in more quality users and to do that we *do* need to expand our range of what's considered on-topic. In the meantime though I feel that as the community grows we will need more close votes to keep up with traffic and this seems like a decent time address all these issues. Maybe not necessarily in this thread.

Comment: I almost wonder if it would be beneficial to get as many users online at a specific time to discuss this similar to how WP Contributors discuss changes ( #slack ). Anybody can join in on the discussion and give their 2 cents. Maybe setting something up for a future date, post a thread about it for visibility and see who comes / active.